# How to change background color of a cell in ObjectListView?

Tags: objectlistview

How to change background color of a cell in ObjectListView? after a CellEditFinishing event is fired? I'm looking at the event args and I don't see how I can access an the cell to change its background.

Yes, this sounds a like a trivial question... but this is no where to be documented in OLV docs, forums, stackoverflow, etc... not even a single example :/ The example in the demos simply cancels the CellEditFinishing event.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it from the CellEditFinishing, but you can put some logic in the FormatCell event that could change the background color depending on the contents (which is probably what you want after a cell-edit).

I used it once this way to indicate various value ranges in different foreground colors.

Take a look at the example from the official documentation [here](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#how-can-i-change-the-colours-of-a-row-or-just-a-cell). Actually, I find the OLV pretty well documented ;)

```
private void olv1_FormatCell(object sender, FormatCellEventArgs e) {
    if (e.ColumnIndex == this.creditBalanceColumn.Index) {
        Customer customer = (Customer)e.Model;
        if (customer.Credit < 0)
            e.SubItem.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Note that you have to set the UseCellFormatEvents property to true.

Comment: I figured this out eventually but it's not exactly what wanted to do. I wanted to convey to the end user that they had edited the current field (regardless of any conditional constraints on underlying value being edited). So would of been nice to just do that  right after the CellEditFinishing event was fired

Comment: @Selwyn: You could always keep track of this information (if a specific cell has been edited) outside of the OLV (probably inside the model object). Set a cell related flag in CellEditFinishing and check it in FormatCell.